# How to specify environment to point Cypress tests at the correct DB credentials?

Tags: cypress

Below is the `index.js` code I am using to connect to a MySQL DB in my cypress test:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
function queryTestDb(query, config) {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(config.env.db)
  connection.connect()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
      if (error) reject(error)
      else {
        connection.end()
        return resolve(results)
      }
    })
  })
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', { queryDb: query => { return queryTestDb(query, config) }, });

  require('cypress-grep/src/plugin')(config)
  return config
}
```

Currently, my test use the DB credentials provided in `cypress.json` on this line:

```
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(config.env.db)
```

But I want the framework to run in different environments, as the database name is different.

I have already created `qa.json` & `staging.json` config files that store the DB credentials like so:

`qa.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "./cypress.json",
    "baseUrl": "myUrl",
    "env": {
        "db": {
          "host": "myHost",
          "user": "myUser",
          "password": "myPassword",
          "database": "taltektc_qa"
        }
      }
}
```

`staging.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "./cypress.json",
    "baseUrl": "myUrl",
    "env": {
        "db": {
          "host": "myUrl",
          "user": "myUser",
          "password": "myPassword",
          "database": "taltektc_stage"
        }
      }
}
```

Here is the command I am currently using to run the tests:

`npx cypress open --config-file staging.json`

I tried to update my `index.js` below, but I get a `Cypress is not defined` error message:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', { queryDb: query => { return queryTestDb(query, Cypress.config()) }, });
```

Can someone please tell me what changes are required in my `index.js` so that I can specify which config file to use when making the DB connection?

Comment: Cypress isn't the right tool for testing server-side NodeJS.

Comment: I'm creating a customer via the UI & validating it's been added to the database

Comment: You could only test the GUI; there's test fixtures which one can load.

Comment: What about the Cypress plugins you can use to query sql db's, etc.?

Comment: Haven't you read what I've wrote at first? Find a test framework for NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Node plugin task, the `config` parameter is equivalent to `Cypress.config()` in the browser-side spec.

You should be getting the correct config resolved after `--config-file staging.json` is applied, so the original code is all you need

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', { queryDb: query => { return queryTestDb(query, config) }, });
```

You can check what has been resolved after opening the runner, under settings/configuration

[image]